# Using Nant, uncomment a block of xml in a file

Tags: nant

I need to uncomment a portion of xml in a file that I am working with in NAnt. Heres a sample of the xml:

```
<navigation>
<!-- Navigation Section
    <something name="" />
    <something name="" />
-->
</navigation>
```

What I want to do is take the --> portion and move it next to "Navigation Section". A global find for --> won't work as there are many --> in the file, as well as under the navigation node. this end comment character is the last one in the navigation node.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hacky but you could do a search for the  string and then work backwards from there to replace the xml comment strings with empty strings. If you can implement that in C# (regular expression would be well suited to this) then it's fairly straightforward to wrap that in a custom nant target (as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537988/how-can-i-use-nants-xmlpoke-target-to-remove-a-node/539365#539365) for a different problem).

A completely different approach would be to store the  nodes in a different file and insert them into this XML file using [xmlpoke](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html). This is probably a better approach than the above but that depends on your exact circumstances.

Comment: xmlpoke is not an option in this scenario.