# How can I use Nant's xmlpoke target to remove a node

Tags: xml, nant, xmlpoke

Given the following xml:

```
<rootnode>
   <childnode arg="a">Content A</childnode>
   <childnode arg="b">Content A</childnode>
</rootnode>
```

Using [XMLPoke](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.86-beta1/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) with the following XPath:

```
rootnode/childnode[arg='b']
```

The result (if the replace string is empty) is:

```
<rootnode>
   <childnode arg="a">Content A</childnode>
   <childnode arg="b"></childnode>
</rootnode>
```

The contents of the childnode have been removed when we actually want the childnode itself removed. The desired result is:

```
<rootnode>
   <childnode arg="a">Content A</childnode>
</rootnode>
```

The childnode must be selected based on the childnode argument.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I hold my hands up! This is a classic case of asking the wrong question.

The problem is that you can't use *xmlpoke* to remove a single node. *Xmlpoke* can only be used to edit the contents of a specific node or attribute. There isn't an elegant way to remove a child node as per the question using only the standard *Nant* targets. It **can** be done using some inelegant string manipulation using properties in Nant, but **why** would you want to?

The best way to do this is to write a simple Nant target. Here's one I prepared earlier:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using NAnt.Core;
using NAnt.Core.Attributes;

namespace XmlStrip
{
    [TaskName("xmlstrip")]
    public class XmlStrip : Task
    {
        [TaskAttribute("xpath", Required = true), StringValidator(AllowEmpty = false)]
        public string XPath { get; set; }

        [TaskAttribute("file", Required = true)]
        public FileInfo XmlFile { get; set; }

        protected override void ExecuteTask()
        {
            string filename = XmlFile.FullName;
            Log(Level.Info, "Attempting to load XML document in file '{0}'.", filename );
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(filename);
            Log(Level.Info, "XML document in file '{0}' loaded successfully.", filename );

            XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode(XPath);
            if(null == node)
            {
                throw new BuildException(String.Format("Node not found by XPath '{0}'", XPath));
            }

            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

            Log(Level.Info, "Attempting to save XML document to '{0}'.", filename );
            document.Save(filename);
            Log(Level.Info, "XML document successfully saved to '{0}'.", filename );
        }
    }
}
```

Combine the above with a modification to the *NAnt.exe.config* file to load the custom target and the following script in the *build* file:

```
<xmlstrip xpath="//rootnode/childnode[@arg = 'b']" file="target.xml" />
```

This will remove the *childnode* with an argument *arg* with value *b* from *target.xml*. Which is what I actually wanted in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

`xmlpeek` only reads values. 
`xmlpoke` only sets values.
Unfortunately, nant does not have an *xmldelete* task.

I solved this issue by creating a nant `<target />` in a nant file I can easily re-use between project.

I chose to leverage nant's built-in `<regex />`, `<echo />`, `<include />` and `<call />` tasks.

#### Advantages:

- Works with regular expression (see disadvantages).
- Can match any text, including XML!

#### Disadvantages:

- Have you ever solved a problem with a regex? If yes, you now you have another problem!
- The regex value in the nant file **MUST** be escaped! (Use an online xml escaper tool).

```xml
<!-- This file should be included before being called -->
<project name="YourProject">

    <target name="RemoveLineFromFile">

        <loadfile 
            file="${delete.from.file.path}" 
            property="xml.file.content" />
        <property 
            name="delete.from.file.regex" 
            value="(?'BEFORE'[\w\s\W]*)\&lt;add.*key=\&quot;AWSProfileName\&quot;.*value=\&quot;comsec\&quot;.*\/\&gt;(?'AFTER'[\w\s\W]*)" />
        <regex 
          input="${xml.file.content}" 
          pattern="${delete.from.file.regex}" />
        <echo 
          file="${delete.from.file.path}"
          message="${BEFORE}${AFTER}"
          append="false" />

    </target>

</project>
```

Below is how to include and call this target. Keep in mind the all the parameters are global and must be defined *before* calling the target.

- `delete.from.file.path`: the path of the file to be modified.
- `delete.from.file.regex`: the regex matching what to removed (and defining BEFORE and AFTER groups).

```xml
<project name="YourProject">

    <include buildfile="path\to\nant\target\RemoveLineFromFile.build"/>

    <target name="OtherWork">

        <property name="delete.from.file.path" value="path\to\xml\file.xml" />
        <property name="delete.from.file.regex" value="(?&apos;BEFORE&apos;[\w\s\W]*)\&lt;childnode.*arg=&quot;b&quot;&gt;(.*?)\&lt;\/childnode\&gt;(?&apos;AFTER&apos;[\w\s\W]*)" />
        <call target="RemoveLineFromFile" />

    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: This answer compliments @Iain's one nicely. One of the advantages it has is it does not require any extra compiling and configuration.